# Render HTML from JSON using angular

Tags: angularjs

I want to create a form HTML on the basis of JSON data using Angular js on which I can easily perform validation also.

Answer (score 0):

Try this module [angular schema form](https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form)
Here is the [sample](http://schemaform.io/examples/bootstrap-example.html) of the same
You can generate form (with validation) using two jsons - form and schema.

Comment: its not so precise. I didnt get the approach of the plugin is working. As my JSON is coming from server side API. There was no point mentioned in it for how to get JSON.

Comment: You can use [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) module to get JSON from your server.

Comment: I don't want to use plugins. I want to do the work withing angular features.

Comment: Then you should try angular [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service